# All all hypo-multiplicative functions linear combinations of quasi-multiplicative functions?

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-functions, multiplicative-number-theory

A function is called *quasi-multiplicative* by many authors if $f(m)f(n)=f(1)f(mn)$, a slight generalization of multiplicativity. (Basically a multiplicative function times a constant is a quasi-multiplicative function.)

Lahiri [1] introduces the notion of a *hypo-multiplicative* function as one where
$$
\left|\begin{matrix}
  f(u_1v_1) & \ldots & f(u_1v_n) \\
  \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  f(u_nv_1) & \ldots & f(u_nv_n)
 \end{matrix}\right|=0
$$
for some $n$ with any $u_i,v_i$ subject to $\gcd(u_i,v_j)=1$ for all $1\le i,j\le n.$ This is a generalization of being quasi-multiplicative, which is the 2×2 case; in fact, any linear combination of quasi-multiplicative functions is hypo-multiplicative.

Lahiri mentions that he does not know if the condition is a biimplication. I was wondering if this was now known, or perhaps obvious to someone here. Are there hypo-multiplicative functions which are not linear combinations of quasi-multiplicative functions?

---

This question was originally posted to [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/891097/1778) but I thought it would get a better response here.

[1] D. B. Lahiri, "Hypo-multiplicative number-theoretic functions", *Aequationes Mathematicae* **9**:2-3 (1968), pp. 184–192. [MR0337736](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=INDI&s1=483672&vfpref=html&r=2&mx-pid=337736)